# ActionbarSherlock - customize submenu on item? (like in Chrome & Opera for mobile)

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile, actionbarsherlock, opera

I am working on an application and using ActionbarSherlock as my actionbar and would like to know how can I customize my submenu of an item like in Chrome & Opera for mobile. Here's a photo of what I would like:

Chrome-
[image]

Opera-
[image]

How can I do it?